# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject of BsonDocument containing null value fails with an InvalidCastException

Tags: json, mongodb, null, json.net

The following test snippet demonstrates an InvalidCastException occurring in SerializeObject when an object value is null or even BsonNull.Value.  If the value is changed to 42, serialization works fine.

```
    var bson = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "key", null /*BsonNull.Value*/ }
    };
    // the following fails with an inexplicable InvalidCastException...
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        bson,
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include
        });
    Console.WriteLine(json);
```

"using MongoDB.Bson" and "using Newtonsoft.Json" are in effect.  Json version is v12.0.1.

Please note that I have also considered using the BsonDocument ToJson method but it exhibits other problems (dealing with enum values), so I am no longer considering this as a work-around.

Comment: How did you end up solving this? I am running into similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could register a custom convention as follows:

```
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreIfDefault", 
                            new ConventionPack { new IgnoreIfDefaultConvention(true) }, 
                            t => true);
```

This will implicitly apply the [IgnoreIfDefault] attribute to all properties when serializing and deserializing.